# How do you mark particular points in a flash (swf) animation?

Tags: flash, flash-cs4

I need to put some markers in my flash animation that can be used to direct a user based on the reputation he has. If his reputation drops over time, he should be directed to a particular point inside the flash animation which is a game. How is this handled in flash cs4 traditionally? Examples and resources will be helpful.

Also, these markers will be saved in the database and tied to the reputatoin engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is coming from a CS3 background.)

You can provide a Frame Label in the frame properties panel. Then in your ActionScript, you can call

```
gotoAndPlay("TheFrameLabel");
```

This wouldn't exactly integrate with the database, though. You'd have to maintain the labels in the FLA separately from those in the database.

Comment: Its worth noting that you can also pass a frame number to gotoAndPlay(5). Although it is better practice to use frame labels. I also have not touched CS4 yet.

Comment: Yes, I will have to make sure these are always in sync. As sometimes I can change my reputation engine to send users to a different point in the flash, then all I have to is change that database field and feed this to my action script as a variable to gotoandplay function.

Comment: How do you create the framelabel in cs4?

Comment: (Pretty sure it's the same in CS4 as it was in CS3...) If you highlight a frame in the Timeline, you should see a text box labeled Frame Label in the Properties Panel. Note that the Frame Label will be applied to the nearest Key Frame, so create Key Frames wherever you want to create labels. (For this reason, I suggest creating a layer just for Frame Labels.)